# Building a custom kernel for a VGA text console

Tags: kernel, vga, grub-legacy

I'm creating a custom minimal kernel in Ubuntu 20.04 that is meant to be run from a USB stick on x86 PC platform to test graphics card hardware. The requirements are PC-BIOS running in VGA text mode (not UEFI).

I turned off "support for frame buffer devices" in the kernel configuration. Now I experience the following: When I use "set gfxpayload=text" in grub I get a "colour dummy device 80x25 console". However, when I use "vga=normal" I get a "colour VGA+ 80x25" console, which is what I want.

Setting vga=normal, however, is deprecated and setting gfxpayload=text should be used instead. I guess I could just ignore the message and use vga=normal, but what's the story here?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* earlier this year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: The issue exists also in later and supported versions of Ubuntu. Upgrading doesn't solve the question.

Comment: Again, the version of Ubuntu is irrelevant, because the problem applies to any version currently supported. Do I have to delete this question and post it elsewhere, so it might be useful to someone else running into the same issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. vga=normal is deprecated under Grub 2, but still a valid Linux kernel command parameter. As for PC-BIOS VGA modes and Grub 2, replacing the "linux" command line with "linux16" and "initrd" with "initrd16" makes all the difference. Make sure to change both lines and you can also use e.g. vga=ask. You can also still boot the system from /boot on a btrfs volume.

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/linux16.html